# Limit in adding Watch address in bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-qt-setup

Is there any limit in adding number of watch address to bitcoin wallet? Am thinking of adding thousands of address to watch list. If i do so what are complications we may face, performance impact?